# Reading a JPEG file with a buffer : segfault

Tags: c, libjpeg

Basically I'm trying to code a reader for JPEG files (using libjpeg) but I have a segfault, and I wanted to know if someone could see where is my error ? I'm sure it comes from the malloc but I don't know. I tried to put some debug by putting some printf but absolutely NONE of them appear, wtf ?

Thanks for your help mates...

**main.c :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include "fonctions.h"


int main (int argc, char** argv){


    int *H;
    int *W;
    int *C;
    printf("COUCOUCOUCOUCOU");
    FILE *fichier = NULL;
    char car;

    fichier = fopen("cara.jpg", "r");

    if (fichier == NULL)
        printf("Probleme lecture");


    lire(fichier, H, W, C);

    fclose(fichier);
    return 0;
}
```

**lire.c :**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include <jerror.h>

unsigned char** lire (FILE* file, int *H, int *W, int *C){

struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;

int n = 0;
unsigned char** buffer;

printf("SHITSHITSHITSHIT\n");
fflush(stdout);
cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo); // Initialisation de la structure

jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo,file);  // file est de type FILE * (descripteur de fichier
                              // sur le fichier jpega decompresser)
jpeg_read_header(&cinfo,TRUE);// lecture des infos sur l'image jpeg


jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);// lancement du processus de decompression


*H = cinfo.output_height;
*W = cinfo.output_width;
*C = cinfo.output_components;

buffer=(unsigned char **)malloc( (*H) *sizeof(unsigned char*) );

while (n < *H)
 {
    buffer[n] = (unsigned char*) malloc( (*W) * (*C) *sizeof(unsigned char *) );
        printf("DEBUG\n");
    fflush(stdout);
     jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo,buffer+n,1); // lecture des n lignes suivantes de l'image
                                          // dans le buffer (de type unsigned char *)
     n++;
}

jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);

jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);

return buffer;
}
```

i compile with :

```
gcc -c -I/usr/local/include *.c
gcc *.o -o programme -ljpeg
```

Comment: Try flushing stdout so that your (buffered) debug statements appear before the program crashes,  e.g. `printf("COUCOUCOUCOUCOU"); fflush(stdout);`

Comment: ok so i put a "fflush(stdout)" on the beginning of the code ?

Comment: And where is the `lire` function ?

Comment: OMG sry ! lire function is "read" ! i translated it but it's bc "lire" means "read" in french :) (i edited)

Comment: @Henleyn: you need to add flush statements _after_ _each_ `printf()`.

Comment: um ok ! so i put fflush(stdout) after each printf ? (i'm pretty new to C so i never used that before)

Comment: Did you realise that you have posted the same code twice? i.e. `main.c` and `lire.c` are identical. I think that the code from `lire.c` is missing in your question.

Comment: sorry wait i'm tired, i edit that
but thanks for the fflush advise it worked well ! 
i edited the post

Comment: ok so with the debug i put with fflush(stdout), i can see that the program crashed right before the affectations of *H, *W*, *C with cinfo.output_height, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `lire`, you pass H, W and C to the function. These are pointers and they are not initialized and therefore you get a crash here in `lire`.

```
*H = cinfo.output_height;
```

You need to call the `lire` function like this:

```
int H;
int W;
int C;

....

lire(fichier, &H, &W, &C);
```

Comment: oh yea i understand now !
thanks Michael ! it doesn't segfault anymore